# laravel error updating the database that uses a foreign key

Tags: laravel

I followed this tutorial from youtube about a job listing laravel project

First problem:

after registering a user and logging in, you will be allowed to post a job listing. The problem is that it takes the user id from the 'users' table and puts it in the 'listings' table and that is the part that (i think) is breaking the application

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`job_listing`.`listings`, CONSTRAINT `listings_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `listings` (`title`, `company`, `location`, `website`, `email`, `tags`, `description`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Senior Laravel Developer, Acme Corp, Miami, FL, https://laravel.com, senior@laravel.com, laravel, javascript, react, backend, hello how are you, 2024-01-24 09:11:13, 2024-01-24 09:11:13))

this is the code that is supposed to add the job posting:

```
public function store(Request $request) {        
        $formFields = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'company' => ['required'],
            'location' => 'required',
            'website' => 'required',
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
            'tags' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required'
        ]);

        if ($request->hasFile('logo')) {
            $formFields['logo'] = $request->file('logo')->store('logos', 'public');
        }

        $formFields['user_id'] = auth()->id();

        Listing::create($formFields);

        return redirect('/')->with('message', 'Listing created successfully.');
    }
```

This is the code for the 'create' function from ListingController:

```
public function create() {
    return view('listings.create');
}
```

I don't know what to try since I am copying the exact code from the tutorial

Comment: "*it takes the user id from the 'users' table and puts it in the 'listings' table*" - Clearly, it doesn't : `insert into listings (title, company, location, website, email, tags, description, updated_at, created_at)`. The user column is **not** defined in your INSERT

Comment: if you check the ListingController.php file, you can see on line number 43, i am insert it into the 'user_id' column

Comment: I tried posting the code, but it said the content of the code is a lot. I couldn't add the entire ListingController.php, so I added the relevant function. I hope this is fine.

Comment: https://github.com/noobuser211/laravel_job_listing

Comment: Just added the 'create' method. Quite frankly, there isn't much to it. It is just returning the view.

Comment: Thanks bro, that error was solved. But I got a new error: Call to undefined method App\Models\User::id()

Comment: @zafeer-ahmad both works [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user). Also `$formFields['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id();` will give undefined function error as  id is not a function. so you have to write $formFields['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;

Comment: Either you use ``Auth::id()`` or ``auth()->user()->id``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert data from create, you need to add columns in your model's `$fillable` array.
In your model, you haven't added `user_id` to `$fillable`

In `app\Models\Listing.php` update below `$fillable` to below line

`protected $fillable = ['title', 'company', 'location', 'website', 'email', 'description', 'tags', 'user_id'];`

Comment: I had it all except for the 'user_id', which I added thanks to your advice. But I still get a new error: Call to undefined method App\Models\User::id().

Comment: @StacFlo you changed `$formFields['user_id']` to `auth()->user()->id()`... revert it back to  `auth()->id()` or `auth()->user()->id()`

Comment: Yeah, changing it to user()->id() worked. The trick was to add 'user_id' to fillable. Thanks for the help.